# Autorizar AJAX no formulario register.blade.php do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, aplicação-web

Estou utilizando os métodos do Laravel para registro de usuários, porém gostaria de utilizar eventos Javascript e Ajax no formulário para adicionar informações especificas de acordo com a informação selecionada no combobox cidade. Ja utilizo este mesmo codigo para outra view do meu projeto e funciona normalmente, mas no formulário de registro quando tento enviar a requisição me retorna com o erro 401 Unauthorized.

Jquery

```
$("#cbx_setor").show();
  $("#lbl_setor").show();

  $("#cbx_setor option").each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });

  $("#cbx_setor").append("<option value=''>Selecione um setor</option>")

  var url = URL + "/adm/setor/consulta";
  var cidade = $("#cbx_cidade").val();

  $.post(url, {"_token" : TOKEN, "cidade" : cidade})
  .done(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $.each(data, function(index, item){
        $("#cbx_setor").append("<option value='" + item.id + "'> " + item.nome +"</option>");
      });
  });
```

Elemento no formulario register.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group row" id="div_setor">
    <label for='nome' id='lbl_setor' class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Setor</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <select id='cbx_setor' class='form-control'> 

         </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

OBS: Ja adicionei um campo anteriormente e realizei o registro normalmente, apenas as requisições são bloqueadas.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi no seu código, você não está passando o token.

Você pode colocar para esse campo ir por padrão em todos os cabeçalhos de requisições para isso basta colocar esta tag meta no seu template (para acompanhar nas demais páginas)

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

e colocar também no javascript do seu template

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

para mais informações da uma lida em:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf